Gaussian integral of imaginary error function squared
I want to evaluate the integral,
\begin{align}
 I &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dz \: e^{-(\Omega -z)^2\sigma^2} \mathrm{erfi}\left( \frac{(\Omega-z)\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \mathrm{sgn}(z) \sin(lz)
\\
&= - \int_{-\infty}^{0} dz \: e^{-(\Omega -z)^2\sigma^2} \mathrm{erfi}\left( \frac{(\Omega-z)\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \sin(lz) + \int_{0}^{+\infty} dz \: e^{-(\Omega -z)^2\sigma^2} \mathrm{erfi}\left( \frac{(\Omega-z)\sigma}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \sin(lz)
\end{align}
Any tips? I've consulted a few standard tables of integrals, but unfortunately none of them include integrand with $\mathrm{erfi}(x)^2$. I'm not sure if a change of variables to $W = (\Omega - z) \sigma$ helps, since this means the integral bounds are no longer from $[-\infty,\infty]$.
